# TalkJS error with User.id: [TalkJS] User: required field "id" is not given or not a string or a number

Tags: javascript, reactjs, runtime-error, chat

Building a React chat application with TalkJS. Below is my "My Network" page with the majority of the logic.

I have a login form with name, email, description and generating a random id. I'm storing this info in Local Storage and retrieving in Network.js. When I click a user to start chat 
I am receiving the following error in the console:

```
index.js:1 Error: [TalkJS] User: required field "id" is not given or not a string or a number.
```

It appears to be happening at this line of code:

```
    const me = new Talk.User({currentUser});
    const other = new Talk.User(user);

    console.log(me);
    console.log(other);
```

I'm reading this as the new variable being created (`me` or `other`) is not accepting the id field from `currentUser` or `user`?

**Network.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { dummyUsers } from './Users.js';
import Talk from 'talkjs';

class Network extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);

    let currentUser;
    const currentStoredUser = localStorage.getItem("currentStoredUser");
    if (currentStoredUser) {
        currentUser = JSON.parse(currentStoredUser)
    }

    this.state = {
        currentUser

    }
}

handleClick(userId) {

    /* Get both users */
    const { currentUser } = this.state;
    const user = dummyUsers.find(user => user.id === userId);

    console.log(currentUser);
    console.log(user);

    /* Create talk session */
    Talk.ready.then(() => {
        const me = new Talk.User({currentUser});
        const other = new Talk.User(user);

        console.log(me);
        console.log(other);

        if(window.talkSession) {
            window.talkSession = new Talk.Session({
                appId: "twBRxQzL",
                me: me
            });
        }

        const conversationId = Talk.oneOnOneId(me, other);
        const conversation = window.talkSession.getOrCreateConversation(conversationId);

        conversation.setParticipant(me);
        conversation.setParticipant(other);

        this.chatbox = window.talkSession.createChatBox(conversation);
        this.chatbox.mount(this.container);

        console.log(me);
        console.log(other);
    })
    .catch(e => console.error(e));


}

render(){

    const { currentUser } = this.state;

    return(
        <div>
        <div className="list-group w-25">
            {dummyUsers.map(user => {
                return(
                    <button onClick={(userId) => this.handleClick(user.id)} className="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start ">
                        <div className="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
                        <img src={user.photoUrl} alt="User" height="42" width ="42"/>
                            <h5 className="mb-1">{user.name}</h5>                                
                        </div>
                        <p className="mb-1">{user.email}</p>
                        <p className="mb-1">{user.description}</p>
                    </button>
                )
            })}
        </div> 
        <div className="chatbox-container" ref={c => this.container = c}>
            <div id="talkjs-container" style={{height: "300px"}}><i></i></div>
        </div>
        </div>
    )
}
}
export default Network;
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code works:

```
        Talk.ready.then(() => {
        const me = new Talk.User({
            id: currentUser.id,
            name: currentUser.name,
            email: currentUser.email,
            description: currentUser.description,
            photoUrl: currentUser.photoUrl
        });
        const other = new Talk.User(user);
```

Anyone care to explain why this is needed and I'm not able to just pass `Talk.User({currentUser})` ?

Comment: It's because `Talk.User({ currentUser })` is passing in an object with a property `currentUser`, not the actual currentUser. You want just `Talk.User(currentUser)`.

Comment: Makes total sense. Thank you

Comment: `Talk.User({ currentUser })` is just a shortcut (called punning) for `Talk.User({ currentUser: currentUser })`.

Comment: Hey Justin, I see you got some fantastic support from Jacob - if you ever run into any issues again feel free to reach out via our (TalkJS) live support, you'll always be able to get a response from a developer.